# "Class No Found" error when running signed applet

Tags: java, applet, code-signing, jar-signing

I have a self signed applet that works correctly (except there is a security warning).
To remove the warning, I bought a go daddy signing cert and signed the jar with this cert.

Now I get a "class not found" error when trying to run the applet from the browser.

help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that browser can download the jar. Type the direct URL to jar file into your browser:

http://www.yourserver.com/yourapplet.jar

If you can download the jar and it is identical to your jar, check the jar itself. Type in command line:

```
jar vft yourapplet.jar
```

and see output. You should be able to find your class

also check:
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_resolve_class_not_found_Exception_in_java

[How do I resolve this Java Class not found exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception)