# maven dependency convergence error

Tags: java, maven

I am getting this weird maven error running **mvn clean install** command for one of our projects ( lets call it A , and version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) :

Dependency convergence error for C:3.2.6-SNAPSHOT paths to dependency are

```
+-A:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
  +-B:3.2.4 
    +-C:3.2.6-SNAPSHOT
```

and

```
 +-A:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
   +-B:3.2.4 
     +-C:3.2.3
```

What I dont understand is that how can the same version of B ( 3.2.4 ) transitively bring **Different** versions of the jar C ( 3.2.6-SN  and 3.2.3 )

Comment: If your artifact B has really a release version it can't the cases that a release aritfact has a SNAPSHOT dependency. There is something really wrong in your build.

Answer (score 0):

It can't. Check your artifact names, and take a look at this:

[Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven)