# Will Maven pick the latest dependency out of two?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey

This question may have an answer already but I couldn't find a satisfying one. I just updated `jersey` jars to the latest one. I get `jersey` dependencies form the `Parent project` which also contains another project as a dependency which uses the lower version of `jersey`. I am not updating the `jersey` jars in this project. After updating the jars I see two versions of `jersey client` one of the them is the latest and the other one is from the project which uses the lower version.Scope is compile. My app is running fine but on the lib folder I see two version of jersey client 1.17 and 2.25.1. Will this cause any issue or Maven will always use the 2.25.1?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven will always take the dependency which is the nearest to the root of your dependency tree. If two different versions are on the same level, the first one which is declared will be taken. Lets take the following example:

```
pom.xml
|--A:1.0
|--B:1.0
|  |--A:2.0
|  |--C:1.0
|  |--D:2.0
|--C:2.0
   |--D:1.0
```

Here, the libraries `A:1.0`, `B:1.0`, `C:2.0` and `D:2.0` are resolved. While the versions of `A`, `B` and `C` are taken because being nearest to the root, the version of `D` is taken because it was declared first.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks SilverNak.