# Maven: Shade version used in third-party dependency instead

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

Say my project is called A, and Foo and Bar are third party libraries. A depends on Foo version 1 and Bar. Bar depends on Foo version 2:

```
A -> Foo version 1  
  \-> Bar  
      \-> Foo version 2
```

With this Maven shade plugin config in my project's, A's, POM

```
<relocation>
  <pattern>Foo</pattern>
  <shadedPattern>FooA</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

the version I use, Foo version 1, will be renamed/relocated as FooA.

Question: is it possible to rename/relocate Foo version 2 instead? I know this can be done if I can modify Bar's POM - however, I cannot, since I'm not the distributor of Bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven)

Comment: @RolandWeisleder - thanks for the link - although, I haven't been able to figure out how to apply the answer in that question to my issue - the other question seems to be related but much more general. Could you help?

Answer (score 3):

Maven does not allow to have a dependency on multiple versions of the same artifact. The dependency resolution works as follows:

> Maven picks the "nearest definition". That is, it uses the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.
>
> "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies. For example, if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0.

Source: [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447665/4365460) the solution could be to produce shaded JARs of each module with such conflicts. With your example, this would be

- create a module "Bar-shaded" which creates a shaded JAR of "Bar" and all of its dependencies
- in module "A" add dependencies to "Foo" version 1 and "Bar-shaded"

Comment: Ah...by `module "Bar-shaded"` you mean I would need to create another Maven project/artifact (with shade plugin) that acts as a wrapper for the 3rd-party Bar artifact?

Comment: @flow2k Exactly

Comment: It would be so great if the shade plugin had an option which can do this for me automatically, so I don't have to create all these shaded wrapper projects (in case there is more than one). But I guess the feature doesn't exist yet...