# How to make dependency in a POM use a particular version of a library

Tags: maven, apache-poi, pom.xml, apache-tika

The library fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf needs Apache POI 3.17. I just updated my project to the latest version of Apache Tika which uses Apache POI 4.0.

Is there a way to specify in the POM to let fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf use Apache POI 3.17 whiles my project uses Apache POI 4.0?

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>${tika.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-langdetect</artifactId>
  <version>${tika.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
  <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you show dependency which you wrote in  pom.xml file.?

Comment: @Tejal added the pom.xml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven)