# Is there any way to apply dependency to one package only?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

If I have a file that is in

```
package com.my.stuff.tests.stuffone;
```

Is there anyway to make a pom dependency apply to that one package only and not to the other

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.some.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            // apply to com.my.stuff.tests.stuffone;
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.some.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
            // apply to all other package
        </dependency>
```

Comment: you'd probably need to use shading https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ to create your own non-conflicting version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven)

Answer (score 1):

Nope - packages in java are simply organizational structures for code, they don't have any other properties.

Once a Jar (dependency) is on the classpath, it's available to the class loader and all other classes under the same class loader (e.g. all other packages).