# Using 2 different versions of org.apache.avro (1.7.7 and 1.9.1) in one application

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'm using maven shade plugin, and shaded jar is used to submit my ETL job. I want to use 1.7.7 and 1.9.1 versions of Apache avro as transitive dependency. But getting an error
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/message/BinaryMessageEncoder`. In the logs, we can see lower version is getting used.
It was all fine before I set `HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true` when running the jar.
What are ways I can have both versions on the classpath? Is it possible using shade plugin?

Comment: Simple answer to this: That is not possible. You can not have two different version of the same artifact.

Comment: It's doable, but tricky, because of transitive dependencies and runtime class losing. The process involves doing roughly what shade does--rewriting FQNs throughout the bytecode. It is quite brittle and error-prone. Why do you think you need both versions?

Comment: _was all fine before I set_ - Then sounds like a separate problem where you should not be including Hadoop **provided** libraries in your own code unless you are sure they are backwards compatible

Comment: Normally **this should NEVER be done**. Check more on [multiple versions of the same dependency in maven / java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven). It is questionable why are you trying to do this. Try for a different solution, or you may want to explain why would you need 2 versions of avro in the same code. Do you have a scenario where.

Comment: This happens quite often actually, if your application code requires new features/bug fixes from newer version of a common utility/tool than the one used by the platform itself.

Comment: avro models directly used in my app are built using 1.9.1 with that I get below error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getJsonProp(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode;
 at org.kitesdk.data.spi.ColumnMappingParser.hasEmbeddedColumnMapping(ColumnMappingParser.java:104) ~

Answer (score 0):

Found that org.apache.avro - 1.8.2 is compatible with both (1.7.7 an 1.9.1) that worked for me.