# mvn dependency:analyze not detecting unused dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have the following dependency on my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I run `mvn dependency:analyze` and this dependency **doesn't** show up under `[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:` so I assume this dependency was being used somewhere.

However I made a project search for `org.apache.commons.httpclient` which, according to the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/index.html), is the root package and I didn't find any occurrences.

I decided to remove this dependency and the project still builds successfuly and everything seems to work. Why is `mvn dependency:analyze` not flagging this dependency as unused?

I also ran `mvn dependency:tree` and found a transitive dependency for this artifact but for a different version (3.0), I don't know if this matters.

Comment: "*I also ran mvn `dependency:tree` and found a transitive dependency for this artifact but for a different version (3.0), I don't know if this matters.*" - Yes it does. This basically means you forced version 3.1 instead of 3.0. So the dependency is used, but transitively. And you overwrote the transitive version.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification @Turing85. I assumed `dependency:analyze` was specific to each version. Is it possible to use different versions of the same dependency inside the same project? If so, how would I find unused dependencies if one of the versions is used and the other isn't?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- See [Can multiple versions of the same dependency be used in a single Maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962607/can-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency-be-used-in-a-single-maven-repositor)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the answer

Comment: Without a full pom file it's hard to guess anything...