# how to import file from one eclipse project to another

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this question must have been asked before and i have gone through the solution but that didnt seem to solve my question.
Suppose I have 2 projects in eclipse .ProjectA and ProjectB and ProjectA has file named FileA in package PackageA and ProjectB has a file named FileB in PackageB.Suppose i want to use a function of FileA in projectB.Is there any import statement which will allow me to do so.I dont want to copy paste the entire fileA in projectB.I just want something like

```
import ProjectA.packageA.fileA
class fileB
{
//calling function from fileA
int somethingsomething = fileA.somefunction();
}
```

I have done things like go to project right click and click on import and import the file.But i dont want the file to be present in my filelist of ProjectB.Please ,Can someone help me with this problem.Is this even possible?

Comment: You can import jar of `ProjectA` in build path of `ProjectB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First way

1. Right click on `ProjectA` and export as jar file.
2. Right click on `ProjectB`, Goto Build path -> Configure build path -> Libraries
3. Add external jar of `ProjectA`

Second Way,

1. Right click on `ProjectB`, Goto Build path -> Configure build path -> Projects
2. Click on Add, select `ProjectA` from list.

After this, you will be able to import classes in `ProjectB` which are defined in  `ProjectA` by,

```
import packageA.fileA
```

Read more at : [Java build path](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm)

Comment: The second way is great. Looked for such thing a long time. Why did i think that one could not just include a .java source file? So i tried to import a .java activity source file which i use in many projects but always moved from project to project. This works all fine. If i introduce an error in the source it won't compile. So it is definitly used. In the manifest i changed the package name for the activity. It compiles and links ok but at runtime i get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` mentioning `packageA.fileA`. Is there something more to it?

Comment: `you will be able to import classes written in ProjectB which are defined in ProjectA`. Now that i look more to that i do not understand. "written in projectB" ? What would that be? Didn't you mean: "you will be able to import and use classes in ProjectB which are defined in ProjectA" ?

Comment: It was a typo, corrected now !! I exactly mean that what you said.

Comment: I am not familiar with android but you can get help for `ClassNotFoundException` from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17408769/1686291).

Comment: Mmmm was not successfull so tried 'First way'. That gives me a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Googling around it looks as if i'm not the first seeing such error. I know now your advices don't work for me out of the box. That is a pitty.

Answer (score 0):

Well your Project B needs the code of File A to execute it. You can either copy the file, or a .jar, or you copy the relevant code into the new project. You cannot just reference a piece of code but not add it to your Project in some way. When building your project to a .jar for example, this piece of information must be present and accessible for the program.