# Configuration of web.xml and spring dispatcher-servlet.xml for spring

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am very new to spring framework so when I am trying to making a simple spring MVC program my server shows this exception report(class not found exception precisely):

If picture is not visible properly then please check complete error list below:
[image]

**I have already added spring distribution jars, commons-logins jar and servlets etc.**

My XML files are as follows:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">  



    <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

For more information please see complete error list:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9999"]
Sep 25, 2014 3:11:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 25, 2014 3:11:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3968 ms
Sep 25, 2014 3:11:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet spring-dispatcher as unavailable
Sep 25, 2014 3:11:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring-dispatcher
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` are you missing a library or an import?

Comment: @Celeo I already added all required libraries

Comment: See [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception).

Comment: Are you using maven to manage your dependencies?

Comment: @Desorder No, I added all jar files manually

Comment: Make sure to have spring-webmvc in your classpath.

Comment: @Desorder it's there.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using it?

Comment: Can you post here the list of libraries you've added to your project?

Comment: Acatually added all spring distribution jars that comes with 4.1.0 and commons-logins jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61862/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-desorder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the list of required dependencies for a plain Spring MVC web application.

[image]

You can download/clone/look the project at

https://github.com/desorder/spring-mvc-test

It's a eclipse project.

Comment: @pushpendra Have a look at my github project and compare with yours. I don't know what the problem in your project is but it might be a very small detail.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue when working with Spring MVC with Eclipse. What happens is that the dependencies are added to the classpath of Eclipse. However the next step is misssed

> 1) Add the dependencies to the classpath using : properties >
>   buildpath  - option on the project in eclipse

if you have already added the dependencies you would want to do the next step for web apps

> 2) Go To Deployment Assembly (project > properties > Deployment
>   Assembly ) click on add : choose "Java Build Path Entries" Select the
>   dependencies added. Click Finish.

**Step 2 should ideally resolve your issue.**

Answer (score 1):

Spring would be like a country:

dispatcher-servlet.xml is the post office for the mail in Spring town, every letter should go through them, but some people keep on sending things with the old web.xml county office (which should be only an intermediary), which is a part of the country that was once great and independent, but now is just a district. May be old and not fancy, but it worked nicely when administered appropriately, some areas of the web.xml county have roads that lead to cliffs 404 meters in deep.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cango.optigo"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> 
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enables the caching through annotations -->
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Configuration for using Ehcache as the cache manager-->
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
          <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="testcache" />
          </set>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- declare datasource bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```