# ClassNotFoundException when running my program on actual device

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I am developing my code project on Windows 8 on Java 8 using NetBeans. 
I created a new Java project (Tester) with one class `ControlGpioExample` (http://pi4j.com/example/control.html).

I set `ControlGpioExample` as setup class, and added the Gpio lib to this project.

Then I created a jar and copied it to the raspberry device.

[image]

Although the device also has libraries, this code fails.

The strange thing is when I execute original jar from RP lib

[image]

everything works well

Why does this work? 
Why doesn't my solution work?

Comment: You might find your answer at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception).

Comment: Which directory contains the relevant libraries? Does `/opt/pi4j/examples/classes` exist? Does `~/Downloads/classes` exist?

Comment: Relevant libraries are in `/opt/pi4j/`. No exist `/opt/pi4j/examples/classes`, no exist `~/Downloads/classes`