# Configuring Jasper Reports on Sugar CRM

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar CRM version 6.5.16 and I installed the Zucker Reports module in order to generate reports. The demo reports that came with the Zucker Reports package had been generating reports without any issues (i.e the 'Opportunities' report) and so I have started to create my own custom reports to use within the application using iReports 5.6.0.

I developed a report using the same database as what my CRM application uses and the data was being displayed as I wanted and have therefore I've been trying to deploy the report onto the CRM application to use within the web page. After deploying I was getting the following error whn attempting to run the report.

```
cmdline: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath "custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/;custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/CustomAccounts2.jasper_files/;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/ant-1.7.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/antlr-2.7.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barcode4j-2.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-anim.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-awt-util.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-bridge.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-css.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-dom.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-ext.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-gvt.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-parser.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-script.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svg-dom.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svggen.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-util.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-xml.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bcel-5.2.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bsh-2.0b4.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-digester-1.7.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hibernate3.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/iText-2.1.7.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-applet-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-javaflow-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jaxen-1.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jcommon-1.0.15.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jpa.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jxl-2.6.10.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/log4j-1.2.15.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mysql-connector-java-3.1.11-bin.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/png-encoder-1.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/poi-3.6.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/rhino-1.7R1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/saaj-api-1.3.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/serializer.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/servlet.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-beans-2.5.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-core-2.5.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xalan-2.7.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis-ext.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/zuckerreports-1.0.jar;" at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain custom/ZuckerReports2/temp/dd12eded-b108-ac55-9905-57149d3cb021/cmd.properties 2>&1
JasperBatchMain :: loading jasper design custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/CustomAccounts2.jasper
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.ReportContext
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParameter.getValueClass(JRBaseParameter.java:147)
at at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain.main(JasperBatchMain.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.ReportContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParameter.getValueClass(JRBaseParameter.java:143)
... 1 more
```

After reading http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-how-install-zucker-reports-i-56 I thought the issue could be down to jar files so I moved all the Jasper jar files the report was using within the iReports application into the CRM application.

[image: highlighted jar files indicate new jar file to CRM directory]

and this change was promising as it gave me a different error message:

```
cmdline: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath "custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/;custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/CustomAccounts2.jasper_files/;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/ant-1.7.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/antlr-2.7.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/barcode4j-2.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-anim.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-awt-util.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-bridge.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-css.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-dom.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-ext.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-gvt.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-parser.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-script.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svg-dom.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-svggen.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-util.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/batik-xml.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bcel-5.2.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/bsh-2.0b4.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-digester-1.7.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hibernate3.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/iText-2.1.7.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-5.6.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-applet-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-chart-themes-5.6.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-core-renderer.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-functions-5.6.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-htmlcomponent-4.7.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-htmlcomponent-5.0.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-javaflow-4.0.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-json.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jasperreports-jtidy-r938.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jaxen-1.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jcommon-1.0.15.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/joda-time-2.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jpa.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/jxl-2.6.10.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/log4j-1.2.15.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/mysql-connector-java-3.1.11-bin.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/png-encoder-1.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/poi-3.6.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/rhino-1.7R1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/saaj-api-1.3.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/serializer.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/servlet.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-beans-2.5.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/spring-core-2.5.5.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xalan-2.7.1.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis-ext.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/xml-apis.jar;modules/zr2_Report/jasper/zuckerreports-1.0.jar;" at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain custom/ZuckerReports2/temp/c6f07bf4-1681-db5e-5243-5714c3143fe4/cmd.properties 2>&1
JasperBatchMain :: loading jasper design custom/ZuckerReports2/resources/CustomAccounts2.jasper
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextElement.readObject(JRBaseTextElement.java:1366)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:823)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:97)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:73)
at at.go_mobile.zuckerreports.JasperBatchMain.main(JasperBatchMain.java:108)
```

EDIT Removed issue with demo report that has been resolved after adding the joda-time jar

EDIT New error message pasted after moving the subreports into the root directory of the Reports directory

Comment: Did you add joda-time lib to cp?

Comment: I only moved the Jasper jars however I am still getting the same error message after adding the joda-time jar

Comment: The same message about *joda-time*? `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant`

Comment: Ahh sorry I was comparing to the new report I'm working on. That has resolved the problem with the demo reports not working. Unfortunately the new report is still showing the same error though

Comment: The question is getting a bit unclear, try to improve it removing all non related information java.lang.ClassNotFoundException = you do not have the library in classpath.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception