# ClassNotFoundException javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi but the class is there

Tags: java, eclipse, jai, javax

I have two similar projects working with Jai and one runs smoothly while the other stops when calling RenderedOp class from the jai_core.jar library, saying that it can't find the class OperationRegistrySpi.

**Both** classes exist within that jar.

```
RenderedOp imagen = JAI.create("stream",imgTif ); //This line throws the exception
```

The log goes like this:

```
GRAVE: >>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/OperationRegistrySpi
>>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>>  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>>  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>>  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>>  at com.sun.media.jai.util.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:267)
>>  at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.registerServices(OperationRegistry.java:2047)
>>  at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.registerServices(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:612)
>>  at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:365)
>>  at javax.media.jai.JAI.<clinit>(JAI.java:560)
```

I have configured the Build Path and the jar file location is the same for the working project and the buggy one.

I'm on Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception

Comment: @AammadUllah Thanks, but I've already checked the build path configuration many (many) times, I was thinking it could be a Jai related issue.

Comment: Can you able to find a class `javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi` using Ctrl+Shift+T in eclipse? If yes how many of them do you find? Its possible that you have multiple jars  **jai_core.jar** of different version. Can you post a screenshot of it ?

Comment: @ChiragParmar I could solve it by deleting all the jar files related to Jai and reinstalling the jai-1_1_2_01-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe package. I think having multiple jai-core library files in different locations made my project behave oddly. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: @AammadUllah- Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by deleting all the jar files related to Jai (jai-core and jai-codec) and reinstalling the jai-1_1_2_01-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe package found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#jai-1_1_2_01-oth-JPR).

The problem was that I was missing the mlibwrapper_jai.jar that comes with the installation of jai.

Comment: "This program requires the installation of Java 2 JRE version 1.3" setup aborted

Comment: Do you know a way to get only the JAR's, say, in a ZIP file?  Those installers are broken...

Comment: Never mind.  I extracted them from the installer EXE with 7z.