# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/OperationRegistrySpi

Tags: java, tiff, mirth

I have asked the same question in this forum as well http://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=217493

Here's my requirement I'm reading the .txt file (Base 64 Encoded) and converting into tif Image file in JAVA. Since creating multiple sliding images is not possible via mirth. I used a Java Library to achieve this. JAR I used are `jai-codec-1.1.3`,`jai-core-1.1.3` and `jai_imageio-1.1`

Now the code I wrote works fine when executing through Eclipse, it reads the combined encoded strings and generates a .tiff file out of it. Im using the same library and calling it via Mirth. It throws the following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/OperationRegistrySpi`

I referred all posts that has same error and tried out including dependent JARS like `mlibwrapper_jai-1.1.3-sources` and `gt-geotiff-14.4-sources` they did not work. Im getting a same error again. Now the confusion is how it works perfectly in JAVA but not in Mirth? Im using Mirth version 3.4.2

Else it would be great if some one could suggest an alternate JAVA library. To generate .txt base 64 encoded to TIFF images.

Comment: Why are you including source JARs?

Comment: Have you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476793/classnotfoundexception-javax-media-jai-operationregistryspi-but-the-class-is-the ?

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes I tried installing the JAI, still it does not work when executing via Mirth. I also used mlibwrapper_jai.jar then I started getting same kind of error

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What do you mean source JARS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686312/what-is-a-sources-jar

Comment: Ok. I will try getting other JARS which is not source jar. But, its the same jai-codec-1.1.3,jai-core-1.1.3 and jai_imageio-1.1 JAR's I'm using and executing via Eclipse its working fine, why not the same work via Mirth? This is what I'm wondering

Comment: I tried adding the other JARS as well it was not working. Im getting the same kind of error @RobbyCornelissen