# ClassNotFoundException even if the jar is in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm facing strange problem. I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException
```

but commons-codec.jar is in the WEB-INF/lib folder. What's going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve this Java Class not found exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception)

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle for managing dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was specifying the class to load in a config file and had an extra space after the class name.  Of course, the error printed that extra space but its invisible obviously so it made it very difficult to debug, as it looked like the class it was trying to find was correct.