# SINGLE LINE of JAVA neuroph code is not working

Tags: java, neural-network, slf4j-api

I made a program that tries to use neuroph made neural network consisting of one line of code (beside imports, main etc.)

```
NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile('path here');
```

The first error I got was:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;

After adding `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar` I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.neuroph.core.exceptions.NeurophException: Class not found while trying to read neural network from file!

I also tried with other versions of `slf4j` I could get. Sounds good, does not work. I have no idea how to begin fixing it.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Are you sure the file contains the contents you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the second error is not related to slf4j , but to NeuralNetwork not finding it's own classes.

Code that throws the error:
https://github.com/neuroph/neuroph/blob/master/neuroph-2.9/Core/src/main/java/org/neuroph/core/NeuralNetwork.java line 683.

See [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception) for some pointers