# When I start running my java application through Tomcat server, I encountered this kind of error. What should I do?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Tomcat authentication filter error.

```
Dec 07, 2017 11:15:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter AuthenticationFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.da.jmrs.webapp.filters.AuthenticationFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1339)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at
```

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5340)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Well, obviously it can find class `gov.da.jmrs.webapp.filters.AuthenticationFilter`. Is that your own class? If not, then you forgot to add the `.jar` file that contains it to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the `.war` file. If it is yours, then you forgot to add it to the `.war` file as `WEB-INF/classes/gov/da/jmrs/webapp/filters/AuthenticationFilter.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath, missing class to the classptah.
Read this topic to know more
[How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)