# Error with android studio class dones not exist

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I installed Android Studio on a new PC but it does not let me compile.
It throws these errors [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POYo0.jpg). I've tried to change the gradle and download the tools. I cannot figure out why it does not compile and throws me these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Ih4.png)

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
22 actionable tasks: 22 up-to-date
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 1676). The daemon log file: C:\Users\alfre.gradle\daemon\4.1\daemon-1676.out.log
Starting 4th build in daemon [uptime: 1 mins 22.119 secs, performance: 96%]
Closing daemon's stdin at end of input.
The daemon will no longer process any standard input.
Using 8 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path C:\Users\alfre\realslif.gradle\4.1\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@580a5b3f
Creating new cache for plugin-use-metadata, path C:\Users\alfre.gradle\caches\4.1\plugin-resolution\plugin-use-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@5808a338
Creating new cache for client-status, path C:\Users\alfre.gradle\caches\4.1\plugin-resolution\client-status.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@5808a338
Creating ClassLoader a2b8d169-6044-43e8-af68-023f562e4641 from {client-owned-class-loader classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.5.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.5.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.5.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.5.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/android/lib/android.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/android/lib/sdk-tools.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/guava-19.0.jar]} and [org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader@3c721afe].
Starting Build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\alfre\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.local.repo2923.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\alfre.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts-remapped\sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp\28vlxmqnnm21es7qn91g496cu\init4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f\classes\sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp.class does not exist.

  > sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp
- Try:
  Run with --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\alfre\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.local.repo2923.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\alfre.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts-remapped\sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp\28vlxmqnnm21es7qn91g496cu\init4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f\classes\sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp.class does not exist.
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ClassesDirCompiledScript.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:346)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.getScript(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:85)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:192)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultInitScriptProcessor.process(DefaultInitScriptProcessor.java:49)
  at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler$1.run(InitScriptHandler.java:51)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler.executeScripts(InitScriptHandler.java:47)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$LoadBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.loadSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:157)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:120)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sync_local_repo2923_f5cghh361q0suewfndg48t1tp
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ScriptClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ClassesDirCompiledScript.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:342)
  ... 90 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: Can you put the stack trace error? Type it all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)