# ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver postgres Foreign data wrapper

Tags: java, hadoop2, foreign-data-wrapper, postgresql-bigsql

```
    =# SELECT code, total_emp FROM sample_07 ORDER BY code LIMIT 3;
    **ERROR:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at HadoopJDBCUtils.ConnInitialize(HadoopJDBCUtils.java:74)

    /usr/local/pgsql/lib under this directory i have got the following JARs
    hive-jdbc-2.1.0.2.6.5.8-7-standalone.jar
    hadoop-common-2.8.3-amzn-0.jar
    Hadoop_FDW.jar
```

Do I need to change any version of the JAR file or Is there something I am missing, created the extention hadoop_fdw

[develper guide for foreign data wrapper](https://bitnine.net/documentations/developer-manual-en.pdf)
[hadoop_fdw wrapper link ref](https://bitbucket.org/openscg/hadoop_fdw)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: How is the foreign data wrapper configured?

Answer (score 0):

Need to restart the database as well in my case, and set the classpath

```
 echo $HADOOP_FDW_CLASSPATH
 /usr/local/pgsql/lib/Hadoop_FDW.jar:/usr/local/pgsql/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0.2.6.5.8-7- 
 standalone.jar:/usr/local/pgsql/lib/:/home/ec2-user/agensgraph/contrib/hadoop_fdw/
```