# ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Tags: android, android-studio, render, preview, android-studio-3.1.4

When i start a new project on Android Studio and then i want to see the preview of the "Hello World!", the program don't let me and drops this message.

[image: This is the capture of the xml and the preview, that don't shows the "Hellow World!" message.]

[image: Message Errors]

[image: My Android Studio version]

The project that i create uses a API 15 Android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwich as a minimun SDK level.

Comment: Search for you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Comment: it all boils down to: use support libraries in version `27.1.1` until `28.0.0` is stable... would vote to close this, if I were not too lazy to find the first one question, which all the others dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

[`View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener` was added in API Level 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener)

> The project that i create uses a API 15 Android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwich

You will want to set the render view to be at least that level to view the preview correctly. (See the Android icon that currently says 28)

Or you can set the compileSdk to be version 28, which shouldn't affect your ability to run the app on lower minimumSdk versions