# why am I getting this exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class I've included all the libraries?

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, classnotfoundexception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Without more information, I would refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17408769/1707353).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your jars aren't being deployed with the app

Comment: Found the solution,thank you for the suggestions Changed from =org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class T0=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer