# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.Pointcut error while starting weblogic12c server

Tags: java, spring, jar, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.Pointcut error while starting weblogic server.

My application is NON-Spring Project. It may be because of external jars that I am using.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Jars that I am using

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-codec-1.8.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-pool2-2.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.jar
ehcache-3.4.0.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
itextpdf-5.5.6.jar
jcommon-1.0.0.jar
jdom.jar
jettison-1.3.3.jar
jfreechart-1.0.1.jar
junit-4.12.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8-beta4-20110826.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.4.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
xstream-1.0.1.jar
activation.jar
jaxb-api.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jsr173.jar
spnego-r5.jar
xng-plugin-sdk.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: No..its on server startup

Comment: Is it a maven project? If so, please show your pom.xml.

Comment: No It is not maven project

Comment: Reformatted the list of used jars.

Comment: Some Jar tries to use this class and It is not available in the classpath. With a dependency management tool like Maven the solution would be easier.

Comment: Thanks @SimoneCasamassa , My issue got resolved the problem was with javamelody.jar and jrobin.jar.