# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.SequencedHashMap

Tags: java, hibernate

I am unable to resolve this error. I tried all the .jar files related to this. I guess I am having some problems in my Hibernate.hbm.xml. Inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you a small example to reproduce this?  You question is very difficult to solve as is.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` means you are missing a class. In this case you're missing an Apache commons library. You should look into using dependency management like Maven or Gradle if you're not already, which will make management of the classpath much easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)