# External Library not able to access folder path

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse IDE 2019-12 and using jre1.8.0_231

I wanted to make a library for an adventure game that was able to read json files to convert them to objects.  When I exported the library to a .jar file (not runable) an then imported it into my test project in order to make sure everything worked fine, I made the assets source folder and put in Lantern.json, fillied out what i needed and tried to use my library to convert the json file's values into an Item object and ran the method.  However when I ran it I got this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader.JSONUtil.getJSONObjectFile(JSONUtil.java:28)
    at com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader.JSONReader.getJSONItem(JSONReader.java:11)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

I have tried researching the error, but to me it sounds like jibberish and doesn't make any sense.

Here are some snippits of whats going on...

```
//Main (located in src folder in project)

import com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader.Item;
import com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader.JSONReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item Lantern = JSONReader.getJSONItem("Lantern.json");
        System.out.println(Lantern.toString());
    }

}
```

```
//JSONReader (located in library)

package com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONReader {

    public static Item getJSONItem(String path) {
        JSONObject item = JSONUtil.getJSONObjectFile(path);
.....
```

```
//JSONUtil (located in library)

package com.ferisjumbo.adventure.JSONReader;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONUtil {

    public static String getJSONString(String path) {
        Scanner scanner;
        InputStream IStream = FileHandler.inputStreamFromFile(path);
        scanner = new Scanner(IStream);
        String json = scanner.useDelimiter("\\z").next();
        scanner.close();
        return json;
    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFile(String path) {
        return new JSONObject(getJSONString(path));
    }
```

[Here is the Project tree if you need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GaAK.png)

If you need aditional information I can put up more. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the line beginning with `Caused by:` in the stack trace you posted. Your code is throwing [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) Maybe this will help: [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that I need to import my json.jar doc to use my methods, seems like a very obvious answer.  hate that when it happens.