# Running jar file returns error: Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a few .class files I'd like to turn into one .jar file. Here is the manifest for the jar file:

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Main-Class: Server
```

Here is the command I'm using to compile the file:

```
jar cfm Server.jar META_INF/MANIFEST.MF ../server/Server.class ../server/message/User.class ../server/message/ServerNode.class ../server/message/ServerHub.class ../server/message/Chattype.class ../server/message/Chat.class
```

and finally here is my folder structure:

```
message-platform - 
   dist -
     META-INF -
        MANIFEST.MF
   server -
     Server.class
     message -
         User.class
         ServerNode.class
         Chat.class
         ServerHub.class
         Chattype.class
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server
```

This is how I execute the .jar file:

```
java -jar Server.jar
```

When inspecting the jar file using Atom, this appears:
[image]

Could someone please help me figure this out? Thanks

UPDATE:
I created the server package and everything is working now. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Manifest files are called `MANIFEST.MF` and are placed in a `META-INF` folder inside the JAR - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html).

Comment: @andrewjames That's true, but maybe the `jar` tool simply reads the information from the text file and adds it to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file? Not sure though (I rarely use the `jar` tool directly).

Comment: @andrewjames fixed it, same result

Comment: Extract that jar file into another folder and check whether it has the exact folder structure you have intended. Server.class should be in root folder, and MANIFEST.MF should be in META-INF, and all other class files should be in there expected locations.

Comment: @MNEMO just added the picture of the extracted file in a different folder

Comment: @Slaw - You are correct about how the input data is used when creating a manifest file via the `jar` command. Bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said that your Server.class does not belong to any package, and if so, your Server.class should not be under server folder in jar file. If you want to treat server folder just as 'src' folder in the project structure, use '-C' option like:

```
jar cfm Server.jar manifest.txt -C server Server.class
```

For all other class files under server/message, you should do the similar.

Answer (score 2):

The package name is **part of** the class name. `server.Server` is not `Server`. I think you want the former, not the later. Change

```
Main-Class: Server
```

to

```
Main-Class: server.Server
```

Comment: Based on comments by the OP, it appears the `Server` class does not have a package statement despite being in a folder named `server`. So `Server` can't be found because it's located in `server/Server.class` and `server.Server` can't be loaded because `server/Server.class` doesn't declare itself as being in the `server` package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix this entirely but I think it'll have something to do with the class path configuration with your IDE. Make sure it's using a standard JDK and that all sources etc are linked up correctly. Perhaps try using the class path option -cp (although most IDEs handle this for you). For example:

```sh
java -cp /home/User/where/my/jar/is -jar example.jar
```

Honestly, I've only really had issues with this when doing some android development (which runs on the JVM itself) so I'm just throwing suggestions. Hope you get it figured out!