# Java Game Development with Libgdx Book Chapter 3 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, libgdx

I saw someone else asked this but that was over two years ago and they never got an answer.  I am trying to run a sample program in the book Java Game Development with LibGDX but I am getting an odd error.  Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Rock
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
at com.mygdx.game.BaseActor.getList(BaseActor.java:319)
at com.mygdx.game.StarfishCollector.update(StarfishCollector.java:35)
at com.mygdx.game.GameBeta.render(GameBeta.java:24)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:232)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInstance(Object)" because "theClass" is null
at com.mygdx.game.BaseActor.getList(BaseActor.java:326)
at com.mygdx.game.StarfishCollector.update(StarfishCollector.java:35)
at com.mygdx.game.GameBeta.render(GameBeta.java:24)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:232)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
11:45:50 PM: Task execution finished 'DesktopLauncher.main()'.
```

I am using intelliJ and the source code can be found:
https://github.com/Apress/java-game-dev-LibGDX/blob/master/Ch03%20Starfish%20Collector/BaseActor.java and also https://github.com/Apress/java-game-dev-LibGDX/blob/master/Ch03%20Starfish%20Collector/StarfishCollector.java

The code for the method is:

```
public static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String className)
{
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();
    
    Class theClass = null;
    try
    {  theClass = Class.forName(className);  }
    catch (Exception error)
    {  error.printStackTrace();  }
    
    for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
    {
        if ( theClass.isInstance( a ) )
            list.add( (BaseActor)a );
    }

    return list;
}
```

and

```
    new Starfish(400,400, mainStage);
    new Starfish(500,100, mainStage);
    new Starfish(100,450, mainStage);
    new Starfish(200,250, mainStage);
    
    new Rock(200,150, mainStage);
    new Rock(100,300, mainStage);
    new Rock(300,350, mainStage);
    new Rock(450,200, mainStage);
    
    turtle = new Turtle(20,20, mainStage);
    
    win = false;
}

public void update(float dt)
{
    for (BaseActor rockActor : BaseActor.getList(mainStage, "Rock"))
        turtle.preventOverlap(rockActor);

    for (BaseActor starfishActor : BaseActor.getList(mainStage, "Starfish"))
    {
        Starfish starfish = (Starfish)starfishActor;
        if ( turtle.overlaps(starfish) && !starfish.collected )
        {
            starfish.collected = true;
            starfish.clearActions();
            starfish.addAction( Actions.fadeOut(1) );
            starfish.addAction( Actions.after( Actions.removeActor() ) );

            Whirlpool whirl = new Whirlpool(0,0, mainStage);
            whirl.centerAtActor( starfish );
            whirl.setOpacity(0.25f);
        }
    }
```

It seems like it can't find the class name rock, so theClass variable stays null and causes an error.  I was hoping someone had a solution because otherwise its a great book.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have .class file mixed with your .java file ?

Comment: `Rock.class` is not in your `classpath`. See this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception

Comment: I tried to add the class to the classpath but it didn't seem to work.  I am using intellij and wanted to know if you had a tutorial or something available.

Comment: Ok, so I did something right.  I got the rocks to work but still not the starfish.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: I found a way to make this work.  For the class name in the getList you need to use .class.getCanonicalName() instead of a string

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me you have to include the package and not just the class name

```
theClass = Class.forName("com.mygdx.game." + className);
```