# How to fix Cannot invoke connection is null error in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I found similar problems with this but haven't found a solution yet. I am making a create account form with a mysql connection but when I try to click the create button, I have this error.[image]

Here is my code for myConnection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class myConnection {
    
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javacontactsapp", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        return con;
    }
}
```

Output when I changed it to ex.printStackTrace();
[image]

```
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javacontactsapp", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return con;
```

Comment: So you ate the exception and returned null. What was the message on the exception? It would be better to have the exception type and stack trace too. Not all exceptions have a message. And you might as well throw the original exception, as shown here you will just get a different unrelated exception later.

Comment: change `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` to `ex.printStackTrace();` and then show us the output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have edited the post to display the output.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` means that the `jar` file that you are using needs to be added to your classpath.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception

Comment: Post text here rather than images wherever practicable.