# Can't use java.io.* on CodeRunner

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Test.txt");
            writer.write("this is a plain text file.\n");
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> 错误: 找不到或无法加载主类 O:WriteFile
> 原因: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: O:WriteFile

This code can run on both eclipse and vs Code but not on Coderunner. How to solve it.

Comment: If you are referring `coderunner` as a mac software then you can run your code in coderunner without saving by simply removing `public` keyword before the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is broken.

**Method #1**

Try adding the classpath while running it.
On windows:

```
java -classpath .;yourjar.jar YourMainFile
```

On Unix:

```
java -classpath .:yourjar.jar YourMainFile
```

**Method#2**

Configure the build path in your IDE and add an external JAR containing your class to the build path.

**Method#3**

Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath#Setting_the_path_to_execute_Java_programs) to resolve the issue.

Note:
You could also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception).

Comment: Thank you for your patient response. I fixed this bug by adding a compile flag "." which represents the current path. I used to not know I have to do this because it seemed that Eclipse and VSCode helped me finish this automatically.