# IntelliJ and Java JDK not working in any directory except Library

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]I can't run any Java application outside the library folder with IntelliJ IDEA. The error I get is as follows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

I've tried to update my JDK version but the problem persists.
Any suggestions?

P.S. If I run `java --version` in the terminal, everything is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: I think the probelma is indeed with the classpath but I didn't understand how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Show your project structure in IntelliJ IDEA. Is your sources folder marked as sources?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is my structure, I added the screen to my question.

Comment: Open your Project settings and make sure there's an SDK set for both the project and the module.

Comment: Left click on Esercizio in the project tab and press F4 (or go to: File > Project Structure > Modules). On the right, select the src map, and press alt + s (or click 'Sources') so the source map turns blue. If that doesn't work, try closing the project, deleting your .iml and .idea and re-open the project, or just create a new one since you seem to be starting a fresh project anyway.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help! The problem was with the directory, oddly IntelliJ doesn't want '/' in the file name, when I removed it, everything worked perfectly!