# Bukkit Server API java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, minecraft, classnotfoundexception, bukkit

I am using an API in my minecraft plugin. I have added the API .jar in the classpath in Eclipse, and it gives no errors, but when I excute a command that uses a class of the API, it says it doesn't find it. It's as if the API is not being exported or something like that. I have tried to change the classpath when I execute the server, this is start.bat:

```
java -classpath .;lib/*; -Xms4024M -Xmx4024M -jar server.jar -o true
```

But it still doesn't work.

[EDIT]
I have removed the classpath and added the .jar to /plugins. I keep getting the error:

```
[13:19:11 WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console command "uhc skin"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'uhc' in plugin UhcMain v1.0
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:826) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:788) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:470) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:437) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1342) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1130) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/PauMAVA/MojangAPI/MojangAPI
    at me.arnaumas.commands.CommandsFacade.onCommand(CommandsFacade.java:55) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.PauMAVA.MojangAPI.MojangAPI
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:155) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:114) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at me.arnaumas.commands.CommandsFacade.onCommand(CommandsFacade.java:55) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-788]
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Oh ok, your problem is totally different. Can you show the om.xml file or gradle one ?

Comment: @Elikill58 I export it with Eclipse, manually. Right click on the project -> Export -> JAR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)