# why terminal give me an error message when I try to use scala?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I already installed java jdk , sbt and scala on my pc and I already set up all path variables. But the terminal give me following error message when I try to use scala:

[image: myfault]

> C:\Users\Ruchira Lakmal>scala
> Error: Could not find or load main class Lakmal\AppData\Local\Coursier\data\bin\scala.bat
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Lakmal\AppData\Local\Coursier\data\bin\scala.bat

May I know what is the reason and what is the solution please?

Comment: Something is passing your `scala.bat` file as a class name to `java`. That's not going to work. You probably have arguments mixed up somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Personal advice, use **WSL** and install everything in there using **coursier** instead of trying to get **Scala** on **Windows** working.

Comment: It looks like a problem with the space character in the directory path

Comment: Try [changing your folder](https://www.minitool.com/news/change-user-folder-name-windows-10.html) to "RuchiraLakmal" so that your path becomes `C:\Users\RuchiraLakmal` (without space), then reinstall everything all over including path variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [changing your Windows folder name](https://www.minitool.com/news/change-user-folder-name-windows-10.html) to "RuchiraLakmal" so that your path becomes
`C:\Users\RuchiraLakmal` (without space),
then reinstall everything all over including path variables.