# Getting error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

In my pom.xml

i already have defined dependency for `com.google.gson` as below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.8.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But getting error JSONElement class not found error while running my App

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:359)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at  org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
        .loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

How to resolve this error?

Tried to change com.google.gson version in pom.xml but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the existing Google folder inside .m2/repository/com

then try once running mvn clean install it should work, provided you are correctly implementing json elements in your code
OR
open library settings in IDE from there click on add library from maven repository and search for required com.google.code version. It will download and do the sync all around..
This will resolve the error

Comment: Thanks @Ravi your 2nd option worked for me  :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) for dependency scope `provided`:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. A dependency with this scope is added to the classpath used for compilation and test, but not the runtime classpath. It is not transitive.

Use the correct scope, probably you want `compile`.

Related questions:

1. [How can I solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-can-i-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)
2. [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)